# Are nested atomic operations guaranteed to be atomic?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic

Apologies if this has been answered already, or if I'm missing something obvious.

I'm trying to understand how deep the guarantees of atomicity go for `std::atomic`. For example, if we have

```
std::atomic<int> a(0);
a.store(1);
```

the store operation is atomic. However, what happens if we have nested atomic operations, such as this:

```
std::atomic<int> a(0);
std::atomic<int> b(1);
a.store(++b);
```

My understanding is that `++b` is atomic, and so is `store()`. Am I right to assume that this is guaranteed to store `2` atomically in `a`?

More importantly, if `a` and `b` are shared between threads `T1` and `T2`, is it guaranteed that `a.store(++b);` performed by both threads is going to store the incremented value of `b` (as seen by the respective threads) into `a` atomically in each thread? In other words, can thread `T2` "butt in" and increment `b` once more *after* `T1` has already incremented it once but *before* the result is stored into `a` by `T1`?

Comment: Assuming `b` is shared between thread, incrementation of `b` can happen before `a.store(++b);`. so value of `a` is not guaranty to be `2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The increment is atomic, and the store is atomic, but the two operations together are not.  It is possible for the first thread to increment `b`, get suspended, then another thread increments `b` and stores that value in `a`, then the first thread resumes and stores it's (now stale) value of `b` into `a`.

Comment: `b` is evaluates only once. so from OP example a would store `2` even if now `b` is `3`.

Comment: Thank you, I suspected as much, but it is good to have it confirmed. So there is no such thing as "nested" atomicity.

Answer (score 1):

Atomicity does not compose.

Assuming nobody else ever writes to `a` and `b` and another thread tries to read both after they exist, and they read `b` then `a`, possible reads are exactly:

```
{b,a}
{1,0}
{2,0}
{2,2}
```

if they read `a` then `b`:

```
{a,b}
{0,1}
{0,2}
{2,2}
```

which in this case is the same as `b` then `a`.

Comment: So the only guarantee is that the reading thread cannot get
    `{a,b}`
    `{1,2}`
In other words, `b` will not be stored in `a` before it is incremented at least once. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

```
a.store(++b);
```

is equivalent to

```
int temp = ++b;
/* other threads can modify `b` but its value has been save in temp ... */
a.store(temp);
```

Comment: Well, there is an argument that the pre-increment operator does not create a temporary value.

Comment: I mean that `operator ++` returns an `int` not a `std::atomic<int>`, so future modification of `b` doesn't impact value stored in `a`.